# Why does my charset encoding conversion only work for lower case letters?

Tags: java, utf-8, character-encoding, iso-8859-1

I have made a work around for my web application, as I failed to se the character encoding to UTF-8 in all scopes when first creating it. I made a simple character conversion java class, so that I could insert character encoding conversion where needed. These are my methods for that:

```
    public static String encodeUTF8ToLatin(String s) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        byte[] b = s.getBytes("UTF-8");
        return new String(b, "ISO-8859-1");     
    }

    public static String encodeLatinToUTF8(String s) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        byte[] b = s.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
        return new String(b, "UTF-8");      
    }
```

I am using these methods due to the special Danish/Norwegian characters `ÆØÅ æøå`. These have been working well for a while now, but I just discovered that the second method can't convert Upper case characters. When sending the String `"Ã†Ã˜Ã… Ã¦Ã¸Ã¥"` it returns `"?????? æøå"`. This confuses me, as the [conversion table found here](http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html) seems to claim that all six characters follow the same encoding.

Does anyone know why my upper case characters does not convert properly here?

**UPDATE:**
From the answers provided, I can tell that I have some serious gaps in my knowledge regarding charsets and encoding. I think I have to just go back to basics, read more, and then I'll decide if the question is salvageable afterwards.

Comment: [Works for me](https://ideone.com/KTLdcQ).

Comment: Does not work here https://ideone.com/BCL9xk

Comment: Well it is not going to work as you are trying to parse an UTF-8 string as a latin string. Try it like this: https://ideone.com/U1Gnk0 (which means: It works)

Comment: **This code is all wrong.** If you can, go back to where you got it from and mark it so.

Comment: You can't have a UTF-8 encoded `String` in Java. They are UTF-16 encoded (also as in .NET, VB4, VBA, NTFS, JavaScript, NCHAR, NVARCHAR, …). How about a `byte[]`?

Comment: I don't understand. My output here is exactly the same as the input String. Anyway, you say I am trying to parse an UTF-8 string as a latin string. What I think I am doing, is that I have a String, which has the bytes which would be presented correctly using UTF-8 encoding, but it is presented using Latin encoding. So I am trying to say that it needs to take the byte array, using latin, and then create a new string using that byte array, but apply utf encoding. And this works, but only for most of the characters, not all of them...

Comment: `String` is not for `byte`s; It's for [`char`s](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html)(UTF-16 code units).

Answer (score 1):

Your encodeLatinToUTF8 converts a Unicode String to a byte array using UTF-8 encoding. Then it decodes that UTF-8 encoded byte array pretending that it is ISO-8859-1 (there is your problem) and converts it to a Unicode string.

Same with the other method.

Your methods are a bit pointless. Strings don't have encoding, as they are already decoded to characters. Character encoding is a way to represent characters as 8 bit numbers so it only makes sense in byte array context.

Comment: The strings I have here as parameters are really sent from a client side, to my server side, and somewhere in that process, these special characters are corrupted. I have tried to make a central fix, but that corrupted the characters in other ways, so I need a way to interpret these characters, convert them, and save them to database. I don't understand why you call my methods pointless. They do work to a certain degree, exactly as I want them to, except that it only works for half the characters, which I do not know why.

Comment: Also, there seems to be a lot of people here telling me to use byte arrays. As far as I understand myself, that is exactly what I do in my methods. I extract the byte array, with the expected encoding, and then create a new String, from that byte array, using the other encoding. There is probably something essential I am not able to grasp here. I really appreciate all of you trying to help me, but I am really struggeling to understand how my approach is different from what you are all suggesting.

Comment: @Torben There is no text but encoded text. I see your point: programming languages tend to have one "string" datatype. But it is important to know that `String` is a sequence of UTF-16 code units for various operations such as length, indexing, literal escapes, ….

Comment: @KjetilNordin The thing you are missing is that the character encoding you are specifying in the String constructor is not something that you _want_. It's description of what you _already have_. So, if you have called getBytes("UTF-8") you have a byte array in UTF-8 and you _have to_ decode it with new String(b, "UTF-8"). But still, the methods you have here are pointless. If you are getting garbage characters, then someone has already called new String(...) with incorrect encoding parameter. Likely someone is reading data without specifying the encoding and resulting in using system default.

Comment: @KjetilNordin Summary: you can't fix broken character decoding after the fact because information has already been lost permanently. You have to find the original bug and fix that.

Answer (score -1):

I finally made it work. I simply used "Windows-1252" instead of "ISO-8859-1" to get the bytes, before creating a new string, using UTF-8.

I created a new method, which works for both lower case and upper case letters:

```
public static String encodeWindows1252ToUTF8(String s) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        byte[] b = s.getBytes("Windows-1252");
        return new String(b, "UTF-8");      
    }
```

I found this answer, by referring to [this page](http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/bug-iso8859-1-vs-windows-1252.html), which states:

> **Symptom** The following characters fail, while other characters display
>   correctly:
>
> €‚ƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š‹ŒŽ‘’“”•–—˜™š›œžŸ.
>
> The trademark and Euro currency symbol, ellipsis, single and double
>   "smart quotes", en and em dash, and the OE ligature characters are
>   used frequently and are most likely to be reported as a symptom of
>   this problem.
>
> **Explanation** The characters in the range 0x80-0x9F (128-159) ... are in
>   Windows-1252 and not in ISO-8859-1. If you have a problem with
>   characters in that range only, it is because the characters are
>   treated as ISO-8859-1 and not Windows-1252.
>
> Look for references to ISO-8859-1 and replace them with "Windows-1252"
>   (or CP1252, or the correct character encoding name for the library or
>   platform you are using.)

The three characters that failed, was `Ã†` `Ã˜` and `Ã…`, all including characters from the list above.

Comment: You should ask yourself why you see this as encoding to UTF-8 when it is actually decoding from UTF-8 (`bye[] b`). The problem is that you have a `String s` that holds not a text value but a representation of UTF-8 encoded text (`byte[]` in some unshown code) that was intentionally mis-decoded using the Windows-1252 character encoding. Fiddling with Windows-1252 is an attempt to get the proper UTF-8 bytes back. A better name, decodeUTF8FromWindows1252Mojibake. A more typical process, use Base64 to create `String s`. (But why not just put the "Ã†Ã˜Ã… Ã¦Ã¸Ã¥" text in your web content files?)

Comment: As stated in the question, I apparently do not understand how these things work at all. Thanks for the attempt to teach me, but I really do not understand. All I know is that this method in the right place, makes my characters show up as I want them, where I want them. Thanks for downvoting, to signal that this might not be a good solution for others. I'll leave the question anyway though.